# Issue with Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript

I am playing around with javascript, so it might sound as a trivial question. In a piece of code like this:

```
function timeFunction(fn, nameOfFn){
var start = Date.now();
fn();
var end = Date.now();
var time = end - start;
console.log(nameOfFn + ' took ' + time + 'ms');
}

function Person(name){
this.name = name;
this.sayName = function(){
    console.log(this.name);
}
}

var bob = new Person('bob');
timeFunction(bob.sayName,'sayName');
```

Output is:

```
result
sayName took 7ms
```

(time will differ everytime you run the code)

Not sure where 'result' comes from and why 'Bob' is not shown.

Comment: I don't get `result` in the console when I run that code - are you doing anything else?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, im using jsfiddle, so it is jsfiddle stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your `sayName()` function `this` is not what you are expecting. It's actually `window`, and so you are logging the `window.name` property (which happens to be "result" in your case - I would guess you're testing your code in jsfiddle?).

That's because `this` in JavaScript is set according to how a function is called, it's not automatically whatever object the function "belongs" to. (In fact, functions don't really "belong" to objects at all - your `bob` object doesn't "own" `.sayName()`, it just has a reference to it.)

MDN explains `this` [in detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

One way to get your code to behave the way you expect is to use the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind):

```
timeFunction(bob.sayName.bind(bob),'sayName');
```

Comment: yes, I am testing in jsfiddle. Thanks, didn't pay attention to tricky this :)

Comment: Cool. I didn't want to go into too much detail about ways to set `this`, because I'd just be reproducing the MDN article in my answer, but now you know where to focus.

Answer (score 2):

`Bob` is not shown because of the different scope of `this` inside `sayName` method: try

```
function Person(name){
   var _this = this;

   this.name = name; 
   this.sayName = function(){
      console.log(_this.name);
   }
}
```

or, even better, use `bind()` as also suggested by @nnnnnn in a previous answer.

(and I can't see the "result" string when I execute your code, maybe it comes from another piece of code)